# how to get Product Code from current product service

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I'm new to spratacus, i want to get product code in type script.
product$: Observable = this.currentProductService.getProduct();
how to get product code? please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question could be rephrased to more specific:
*How to get the value from the `RxJs` stream of data in Angular?*

#### Answer:

It depends, where you want to access the value:

a) Most likely: you want to get it in the HTML template of your component. Then use Angular's `async` pipe:

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="product$ | async as product">
  <!-- use `product` variable here -->
</ng-container>
```

b) Or in your Typescript class (of component or service). Then you can subscribe to the observable to get the value. That said, it's not recommended approach, because then you need to manually dispose subscriptions **to avoid memory leaks**!

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.sub = this.product$.subscribe(product => {
    // use `product` variable here
  })
}

/*...*/

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.sub?.unsubscribe();
}
```

#### Referecnces

- RxJs Observables are very powerful for managing asynchronous push-based streams of data. Angular team decided RxJs to be a first-class citizen. Spartacus also recommends using RxJs Observables and reactive approach. Read more here: https://angular.io/guide/observables .
- That said, if you want to avoid observables as much as possible, you may be interested in this article https://dev.to/angular/how-to-avoid-observables-in-angular-273h